# Page is flickering on scroll

Tags: html, css, sass, internet-explorer-11

I have fixed sidebar at left and fixed header at the top. in IE browser the page scroll is working fine but after clicking on Load More option. after that page is flickering on scroll

To resolve the flickering issue, I added some CSS of position as well

```
html, body {
    -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 16.66%;
    transform: translate(0,0);
}
.side-bar {
    height: 100%;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width: 16.6%;
}
```

Comment: pls share html code also. or remove -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar from html,body  and try

Comment: Your above code is not enough for producing the issue with IE 11. I suggest you to post proper example code that we can try to run with IE to check the issue. it can help us to understand the issue in better way. Thanks for your understanding.